# Is there a url shortener service that allows custom link creation via API?

Tags: api, url-shortener, custom-url

For example, bit.ly allows to manually specify a URL like http://bit.ly/urlwiki , but this capability has been removed from their [API](http://dev.bitly.com/api.html). Is there another popular url shortener service that supports this? Goo.gl does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [is.gd](http://is.gd/apishorteningreference.php) they claim to support a `shorturl` parameter.

Comment: Looks like their API does support this. The service itself looks somewhat quirky, but does address questions about its business model and future existence in the FAQ.

Comment: It's quite popular, but indeed it doesn't look very slick. Anyway, if it works...